# Find references to specific column in Oracle in Jobs and Procedures

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for a query allowing me to query all the tables, views, **JOBS**, and **PROCEDURES** in the oracle database.  I've found some links to queries that will work for the tables and views but I need **jobs** and **procedures**.  If one query can't be used for all this, I need at least job and procedures.

Here is what I found for the tables and views:

```
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns
```

TIA

Comment: What sort of jobs?  Jobs scheduled via `DBMS_JOB`?  Or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`?  If you mean `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, do you really mean jobs rather than processes, chains, etc.?  For procedures, do you want just standalone procedures?  Or including public procedures in packages?  Are you trying to get private procedures in packages as well?  Do you want functions or just procedures?

Comment: @JustinCave Basically, I need to find any reference to a particular column. Each occurrence will be reviewed to determine if the reference/use needs to be updated.  Does that help narrow down?

Comment: How would a job refer to a column?  Would the job be calling a procedure that refers to a column?  Do you only want procedures?  Or any bit of code that could reference a particular column?

Comment: @JustinCave - good question on the job - I was just asked to include the jobs in the searches.  My guess is that the job may call a query and the query may contain the column name in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like

```
SELECT name, type, line, text
  FROM user_source
 WHERE lower(text) like lower('%<<column name>>%');
```

That will show you any line of code in any pL/SQL object (package, package body, procedure, function, trigger, type, etc.) that contains the column name.  If there are multiple tables with identically named columns (i.e. a column `name` is found in many different tables), all instances will be identified.  There isn't a really great way, short of inspecting the code, to figure out which queries refer the `name` column in one particular table.  You could potentially look to see whether the `NAME` and `TYPE` from `USER_SOURCE` appear in `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` as referencing the particular table you're interested in.  But that just shows you table-level dependencies at an object level and your object may depend on a large number of different tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_SOURCE 
WHERE upper(text) like upper('%<<column_name>>%');
```